# Python - Instance as Attributes

Tags: python, class

When I was learning the Python Crash Course, one question that is not answered in the book is to use an Instance as Attributes.

Let me show a quick example:

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank()

    def get_car_info(self):
        long_name = self.make + ' ' + self.model
        print('The car is', long_name)

class Tank():
    def __init__(self, tank_size=20):
        self.tank_size = tank_size
    def tank_info(self):
        print('The tank size is', self.tank_size, 'gallons')

my_car = Car('Audi', 'S4')
my_car.get_car_info()
my_car.tank.tank_info()

>>>
The car is Audi S4
The tank size is 20 gallons
```

Apparently, I created two classes named Car and Tank, I want to use the Tank class instance as an attribute for the Car. The codes will work out, no problem here.

But what I noticed is that the code that I invoke the Tank method:

```
my_car.tank.tank_info()
```

If I understand correctly, the first 'tank' should mean the class 'Tank'. So why should I lowercase it? I tried to upper case, the code won't work.

Comment: `my_car` is an instance of `Car`.  `my_car` has an attribute named `tank` which was assigned an instance of `Tank` when it was created. `my_car.tank. ...` is accessing `my_car`'s `tank` attribute`.

Comment: `self.tank = Tank()` assigned an instance; `self.tank = Tank` would have assigned the class itself.

Comment: @wwii thank you so much!! this is crystal clear now!!

Answer (score 1):

if..

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tank = Tank()
```

was

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.tnk = Tank()
```

Then you would call `my_car.tnk.tank_info()`

If it was

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.t = Tank()
```

Then you would call `my_car.t.tank_info()`.

So to answer your question you are **not** referring to the class `Tank` **but** you are referring to a **member** of class `Car` which is of type class `Tank`

Comment: I see, so the tank is really not referring to the Tank class, but the 'tank' under 'self.tank'. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Because an attribute will have the name *that you give it*. One **could** give it the same name as the class-name, but that is generally avoided, and by convention, attributes are `snake_case` in Python. But there is nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> class Bar:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.Foo = Foo()
...         self.foo = Foo()
...         self.FOO = Foo()
...
>>> b = Bar()
>>> b.foo
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1021c2710>
>>> b.Foo
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1021c26d8>
>>> b.FOO
<__main__.Foo object at 0x1021c2748>
```

This is a contrived example of a `Bar` object that has three attributes, all three of which are different instances of `Foo`, and I used a different style to name each of them.

I think that one fundamental thing you must grok is that **you've always been using instances as attributes**. Everything is an instance. `str` objects are instances of class `str`, `int` objects are instances of class `int`, `list` objects are instances of class `list`, just like `Foo` objects are instances of class `Foo`. *Everything is an object in Python*.